# Automatically generate folder and .js files from command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, command-line

I'm working on a React app where I frequently copy and paste the same three files to a new directory every time I create a new component. Each file has a list of imports at the top and a `class` declaration in the body.

**What are my options** and **are they any examples** for **writing a tool** that can automatically generate the folder and its contents, with the imports and class declarations pre-written for me, based on the name of the React component?

I want the end result to look like this:

```
/ComponentName/
-- ComponentName.store.js
-- ComponentName.actions.js
-- ComponentName.react.js
```

Comment: Node script, editor script, bash script...

Comment: I'm returning to this question after many years to recommend a combination of `inquirer` and `fs` as an excellent way to solve this particular use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[plop](https://github.com/amwmedia/plop) is a pretty easy to use tool for generating directories and files. It uses [handlebars](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/) templates to create files, and you can build custom prompts to customize the scaffolding that you create.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Plop does pretty much exactly what I wanted to do.